# Uploading file with sFTP usnig asp.Net throws Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, ftp, sftp

I'm having a code to upload a file via sFTP using "**SharpSSH - A Secure Shell (SSH) library for .NET**" of Tamir Gal.

It works fine but in some cases I get throws the "`Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException`" exception.
Any clue what it could be?

Comment: Problem solved, There is no permission to write to that FTP folder. I have tried with fileZilla and managed to access that folder but when I tried to place a file I got an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, There is no permission to write to that FTP folder. I have tried with fileZilla and managed to access that folder but when I tried to place a file I got an error.

The error did not mentioned what was the reason - so best it to try check it with another toll like FileZila.

Answer (score -1):

```
 //Esto funcionara al momento de hacer el Get tenemos que especificar el      //directorio principal del FTP+nombre del archivo

   private static bool descargar_archivos()
        {
            Sftp _sftp = new Sftp(Servidor_FTP, Usuario_FTP, Contrasena_FTP);

            _sftp.Connect(Puerto);

            var lista = _sftp.GetFileList(Directorio_inicio_FTP);

            foreach (string dir in lista)
            {
                if (dir.Length > 4)
                {
                _sftp.Get(Directorio_inicio_FTP+dir, Directorio_Destino + dir);

                }
            }
            _sftp.Close();

            return true;
      }
```

Comment: You add code is good, but explain as per question that how it will help.